# Amazon EMR cluster details needed using AWS cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

What AWS cli command I used to get the AWS emr cluster **CPU core, Memory and number of nodes?**
I used AWS emr describe-cluster. But, it's not return what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Cluster.InstanceGroups` there is a list of different instance groups. For each one there is a `RunningInstanceCount` attribute. The sum of all those in all groups is your number of nodes.

For each instance group there is an `InstanceType` attribute. You can use that to figure out the number of cores and memory. Go to https://ec2instances.info and look for those instance types to see its specs. For example, if you have one instance group of 10 `m3.xlarge` then you have a total of 10*4 vCPUs and 10*15 GB of RAM.